# Elasticsearch structure for repetitive searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have system which is importing data (with same structure) via API every day and searches it for keywords. Every day new data appear, so I download it repetitively. 
After the searching of keywords, I save results somewhere else.
I need only to keep data imported in last three months.
I want to use elasticsearch for full-text search because of stemming and things. 
I need some advice regarding the structure of elastic db.

Is it better to create new index with timestamp in its name for every import and delete indexes older than 3 months or is it better to keep all data in one index even if I want to search only in newly imported data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [time-frame based indexing strategy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html). Elasticsearch allows you to easily manage this with an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html), which will allow you to add all your data to an alias. For example, you can create a template like this:

```
PUT _template/my_index_template
{
  "template":"my_index_*"
  "aliases:{"my_data":{}}
}
```

This will mean that you can make a document insert request to any index that matches the pattern "my_index_*" (i.e. it starts with `my_index_`). If you dynamically include the date in your index name that will make your time based indexing. e.g. data from the 31st of August 2016 should be stored in `my_index_20160831`, and it will be available for search from the alias listed in the above defintion, e.g. an HTTP POST request to `my_data/_search` will return data for your time framed indices.

You'll then end up with lots of indices being stored, and a call to `_cat/indices` will start to look like this:

```
my_index_20160829
my_index_20160830
my_index_20160831
```

Now you can use curator to look for indices that are older than a certain time period. This is a command line tool that allows you to specify a pattern of indices to remove. To test it out you can use the command:

```
curator show indices --prefix my_index --older-than 3 --time-unit months --timestring %Y%m%d
```

This will show you all the indices it's going to delete, then to actually delete the indices change `show` to `delete`

More info can be found in the index subcommand [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/3.5/indices-subcommand.html). Note that this is version 3.5 of curator. The syntax for version 4 has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... actually wasn't tried it, but it seems logical:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/curator-tending-your-time-series-indices

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about.html

Thanks to this post I'll have solution when I'll need it :)

Comment: Using curator to deal with time-base index works very well. It's what we are using: We have one index per day and a cronjob running curator, deleting older index.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some day. If there would be about 90 indexes not more, then I suggest you to do separate indexes. Getting data will be faster than querying them using the second option.